# How to get java control panel cache path programatically in java?

Tags: java, caching, applet

I am working in Applet. I want to delete java cache(primarily it is in folder sun\deployment). We can change this path using Java control panel. Suppose someone has changed that path at client side. Then I want to get this path in Applet. So I could delete it on logout.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a guaranteed way to get the java cache path programatically.  But it is probably moot anyway.  Unless your applet is "trusted":

- it is unlikely it will have permission to find out what the cache location is, and
- it is unlikely it will have permission to delete files in the cache ... or anywhere else on the user's machine.

---

FWIW, if your applet has permission to read files on the user's machine, it should be able to load the [Deployment Configuration File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html) into a `Properties` object and get the cache directory location(s) from the relevant properties.